# Getting "TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'" for linear regression in python

Tags: python, data-science, linear-regression, cross-validation

What I'm trying to do:

1. Fit a linear regression model on data from PCA transformation
2. Use that linear regression model to perform cross-validation

```
ks = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,15,20]
mean_val_mse = []
# loop through all k values
for k in ks:
    # instantiate pca and set n_components = k
    pca = PCA(n_components=k)
    # fit and transform
    # fit learns the number of components, transform actually reduces the dimensions
    x_train_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_train_scaled)
    
    # create linreg and fit it on pca data
    lr = LinearRegression().fit(x_train_pca, y_train)
    cv = cross_validate(lr, X=x_train_pca, cv=10, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', error_score='raise')
```

When I do so, my cross-validation is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
from line: cv = cross_validate(lr, X=x_train_pca, cv=10, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', error_score='raise')
```

I've checked that my y_train is the correct shape and run through the syntax but I'm not seeing a reason why it would give this error.  Am I instantiating the LinearRegression wrong or is the error somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never dealt with Machine Learning, but the error message says you didn't supply y into that last line, so maybe try

```
cv = cross_validate(lr, X=x_train_pca, y=y_train, cv=10, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', error_score='raise')
```

source:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate